# JAXB how to pass XmlRootElement name at XmlElementRef

Tags: xml, jaxb, annotations

I tried to find the solution which will fit in my problem, but with no success.
Here is the problem:

I have got following part of XML structure (which I have no influence on)

```xml
<users>
  <array>
    <item>
      <username></username>
      <email></email>
    </item>
    ...
    <item>
      ...
    </item>
  <array>
</users>
```

I Have following classes structure for that part of XML:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "users")
public class XmlUsers extends XmlData
{
    @XmlElement
    public XmlArray array;
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "array")
public class XmlArray
{
    @XmlElementRef(name = "item")
    public List<XmlItemData> items;
}

@XmlSeeAlso({ XmlUserData.class })
public abstract class XmlItemData
{
}

@XmlRootElement
public class XmlUserData extends XmlItemData
{
...
}
```

I want to wrap XmlUserData by 'item' or 'user' tags, so I don't want to annotate XmlUserData root element name.

How to do this at XmlArray level?
As you can see I have tried to name XmlElementRef, but this results in items to be null...

**EDIT:**
**I'm guessing I have removed user's comment accidentally (I don't remember his/her name). Please, excuse me for that.** It was about using XmlElement instead of XmlElementRef. It helped together with XmlTransient added also on XmlItemData class. But, now I have got list of null elements. Here is my XmlUserData class:

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class XmlUserData extends XmlItemData
{
    @XmlElement(name = "username")
    public String        username;

    @XmlElement(name = "first_name")
    public String        firstName;

    @XmlElement(name = "last_name")
    public String        lastName;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "links", required = false)
    @XmlElements({ @XmlElement(name = "delete"), @XmlElement(name = "next"),
            @XmlElement(name = "self"), @XmlElement(name = "users"),
            @XmlElement(name = "watched") })
    public List<XmlLink> links;

    @XmlElement(name = "url")
    public String        url;

    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    public int           id;

    @XmlElement(name = "fullname")
    public String        fullname;

    @XmlElement(name = "email")
    public String        email;
}
```

**EDIT2:**
Unknown user, please, could you post your response again, so I could mark it as a helpful one?

And I have still problem with list of XmlItemData elements, which should be of XmlUserData type, but they are null...
Any idease, what am I doing wrong...?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT3:**
I have marshalled my class structure with JAXB and it looks like below:

```
<rsp>
  <total_results>0</total_results>
  <users>
    <array>
      <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xmlUserData">
        <id>0</id>
      </item>
    </array>
  </users>
</rsp>
```

Could this line at item tag be expected by unmarshaller? Does its presence have any impact on being unmarshalled message...?

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xmlUserData"
```

Comment: Hello. Did you find solution of your problem? Could you share it, if you did?

Comment: Sorry for late response. No, I don't remember I found one, so the question still remains open.